# Modifying every tuple (and eventually just removing) from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
tradeRanges = [(0,3), (10,14), (16,16), (21,23), (25,25)]
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Take every tuple and analysing the difference between the two numbers;
2. If  this difference is non-zero, then I'd like to append a third element which is in fact the difference of this two numbers; if it's zero, I'd just like to pull the tuple out of the list.

The final output, hence, would be this:

```
tradeRanges = [(0,3,3), (10,14,4), (21,23,2)]
```

With this purpose I have tried to write the following script:

```
for tups in tradeRanges:
    tradeRanges.remove(tups)
    tups = list(tups)
    lenTup = tups[1]-tups[0]
    if lenTup > 0:
        tups.append(lenTup) #so when it's done I would have the list into the same order
        tups = tuple(tups)
        tradeRanges.append(tups)
```

The problem here is that it skips the elements. When it gets the element (0,3) and remove it, rather than saving in memory the element (10,14) it will save the element (16,16). I have a vague idea of why this happens (probably the for loop is taking care of the positioning of the elements?) but I have no clue how to fix it. Is there any elegant way or I should use some control variables to take into account the position of the elements within the list? 
            tups = tuple(tups)
            tradeRanges.append(tups)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tradeRanges = [(0,3), (10,14), (16,16), (21,23), (25,25)]
print [(n1, n2, abs(n1-n2)) for n1, n2 in tradeRanges if n1 != n2]
# [(0, 3, 3), (10, 14, 4), (21, 23, 2)]
```

Comment: You solved in 4 mins what I'm struggling about for two hours. Well, thanks (it works perfectly)!